# ul list elements overflowing parent div

Tags: css, html-lists

I feel like this is probably a really dumb question, but unfortunately I have to ask it.

How can I keep my unordered list from overflowing its parent div? I know that the float:left on the li elements is causing it to overflow the parent div, but I need the li elements to float so they can be horizontal. Not sure what else to do.

Here's what I have so far http://jsfiddle.net/thwackukulele/vzzqY/

And here's what I want it to look like

[image]

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't seem to reflect your question.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the fiddle. Should be on here http://jsfiddle.net/thwackukulele/vzzqY/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want floated elements to fill their parent container without explicitly settings a height, use `overflow: auto` on the parent. If you give the ul the `overflow: auto` property, it'll work as per your screenshot.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vzzqY/7/

Comment: Thank you so much! One of those things I just never would have thought to try, and it works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Set a height of 125px to `.b1bkgd`

```
.b1bkgd {
    background-color: #F2EEE7;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 0 45px;
    height: 125px;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/zCXsc/1/